# 'df' command doesn't list /home directory

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, command, df

In [the book I am reading](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php), the output of `df` command is shown like this:

```
Filesystem 1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2   15115452  5012392   9949716  34% /
/dev/sda5   59631908 26545424  30008432  47% /home
/dev/sda1     147764    17370    122765  13% /boot
tmpfs         256856        0    256856   0% /dev/shm
```

But when I run the same command (whilst passing the `-h` parameter) on my Ubuntu server (VirtualBox VM), the output is like this:

```
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/a-root  4.2G  1.1G  3.0G  26% /
udev                741M  4.0K  741M   1% /dev
tmpfs               300M  268K  300M   1% /run
none                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                750M     0  750M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1           228M   27M  190M  13% /boot
```

What I want to know is, why is `/home` directory missing? And what exactly is the criteria that the listed directories fulfill? (I mean, `/` is listed, but not `/home`. But `/run` is there, and also `/run/lock` and `/run/shm`. Why the bias?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

df shows you the utilization and free space on filesystems. Obviously, on your machine, /home is not a filesystem but a mere directory.

Comment: So, in simple terms, `/home` isn't listed because it isn't on a different partition or device; and in my case, it's in the `/` (root) file system itself, right?

Comment: yes, very much so... But if you are using LVM (logical volume manager) every filesystem doesn't have to reside on a different partition. One partition can be made looking like multiple partitions. Hence the name, Logical.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, you can type `mount` to check currently mounted filesystems. Whatever filesystems `df` displays, they should be on that list, too. If you want to check how much of the disk space does your /home directory use, you can do `du -sh /home` (if that's what you originally intended).